# Spring Security: PasswordEncoder mapped for the id “null”

Tags: java, spring-security

Использую Spring 2.2.5.RELEASE

При отправке GET запроса с именем пользователя и паролем, получаю ошибку вида:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: There is no PasswordEncoder mapped for the id "null"
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder$UnmappedIdPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:250) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.crypto.password.DelegatingPasswordEncoder.matches(DelegatingPasswordEncoder.java:198) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$LazyPasswordEncoder.matches(AuthenticationConfiguration.java:312) ~[spring-security-config-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.additionalAuthenticationChecks(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:90) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:166) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:195) ~[spring-security-core-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
```

Конфигурация написана таким образом:

```
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurityConfiguration_InMemory extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("user").password("password")
                .roles("USER");
        auth.
                inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").
                password("password")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .httpBasic().and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/user/")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user/")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/api/user/**")
                .hasRole("USER")
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.DELETE, "/api/user/**")
                .hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
                .csrf()
                .disable();
    }
}
```

Как можно исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Причина** возникновения проблемы:

> пароль не может быть декодирован, поскольку кодировщик паролей не был
> настроен для нашей аутентификации в памяти.
> [Источник](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-5-default-password-encoder#springSecurity4)

[Начиная с версии Spring Security 5.0](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#authentication-password-storage-dpe) используется `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` вместо `NoOpPasswordEncoder`. Также альтернативным вариантом может быть `BCryptPasswordEncoder`, но лучше `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`.

Для решения данной ошибки можно, используя [NoOpPasswordEncoder](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.2.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/api/index.html?org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/User.html) в методе `inMemoryAuthentication`, добавить `{noop}` (сокр. от [No Operation](https://www.noop.com.au/noop-meaning/)) по принципу:

```
   @Autowired
   protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().
                withUser("user").password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER");
        auth.
                inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("admin").
                password("{noop}password")
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
```

Но это небезопасно, т.к. `NoOpPasswordEncoder` является устаревшим:

> **Deprecated.**  This PasswordEncoder is not secure. Instead use an
> adaptive one way function like BCryptPasswordEncoder,
> Pbkdf2PasswordEncoder, or SCryptPasswordEncoder. Even better use
> DelegatingPasswordEncoder which supports password upgrades.

Аналогично можно воспользоваться `BCryptPasswordEncoder`:

```
@Bean
public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Autowired
protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .roles("USER");
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
            .withUser("admin").password(passwordEncoder().encode("password"))
            .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
}
```

Или же `DelegatingPasswordEncoder`:

```
   protected void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        PasswordEncoder encoder =
                PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder();
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password(encoder.encode("password"))
                .roles("USER");
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("admin").password(encoder.encode("password"))
                .roles("USER", "ADMIN");
    }
```

См. также [примеры](https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-security-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null/) на [англ.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49654143/spring-security-5-there-is-no-passwordencoder-mapped-for-the-id-null).